# Phalcon count in volt

Tags: count, categories, phalcon, volt

I have a counting problem in phalcon volt. I have a table named `category` and there I have two columns `id` and `cname`, and also have a table blog and there is a column `category`. I want to show how many post have in each category.
When I insert a post into blog table, in category column I'm inserting its category `id`. First of I just retrieve list of all category like this:

```
[controller]
$categories = Category::find();
$this->view->setVar('category', $categories);
$cx = Blogs::find();
$this->view->setVar('cates',$cx);

[Volt]
{% for categories in category %}
<a href="blog/category/{{categories.cname}}" class="tags">{{ categories.cname }} 
<span>[ 
{% for cx in cates %}
    {%if cx.category === categories.id %}
        <?php echo(count($cx->category)); ?>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Its render like "1 1 1" or "1 1" or "1" but it should render like "3" or "2" or "1" whats my wrong?

I also tried like this but did not get the expected output:

```
{% for categories in category %}
<a href="blog/category/{{categories.cname}}" class="tags">{{ categories.cname }} 
<span>[ 
{% for cx in cates %}

{%if cx.category === categories.id %}
{% if loop.first %} {{ loop.length }} {% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
]</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Its hard to follow your example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Sir, its not working. But i just solved my problem like this :

```
[controller]
$categories = Category::find();
$this->view->setVar('category', $categories);

[volt]

{% for categories in category %}
<a href="blog/category/{{categories.cname}}" class="tags">{{ categories.cname }} 
<span>[ 
<?php 
$catcount = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.category FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.category = $categories->id");echo(count($catcount));
?>
]</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now its working as expected. and here i dont make any relations ion model.Is it ok Sir. Please! Thnx

Comment: You arent really using the power of Phalcon there. Plus, you should avoid using that query in volt, its not good for your MVC structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined your relationships between your models in Phalcon?
If so, you can use the built in commands to query the total amount of posts for each category

Example from the documentation:

> You can also use “count” prefix to return an integer denoting the count of the related records:

```
$robot = Robots::findFirst(2);
echo "The robot has ", $robot->countRobotsParts(), " parts\n";
```

I don't have much experience with Volt templating, but I guess it will be something like:

```
{% for categories in category %}
<a href="blog/category/{{categories.cname}}" class="tags">{{ categories.cname }} 
<span>[ 
  {{ categories.countBlogs }}
]</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Refer to: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#taking-advantage-of-relationships

**UPDATE - model relations**

[model: Category]

```
public function initialize()
{
    // id => primary key name of the Category table
    // Blogs => name of the table you want to create a relationship with
    // category => name of the foreign key column in your relationship table
    $this->hasMany('id', 'Blogs', 'category');
}
```

[model: Blogs]

```
public function initialize()
{
    // category => blog column name which refers to the ID in the Category table
    // Category => name of the Category table
    // id => name of the primary key column in the Category table
    $this->belongsTo('category', 'Category', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Sir, i'm unable to figure it properly can u please give a working code as my example code? and here may be something went wrong that is im trying to render all from my blog table and want to count category column which is matched with category tables id column. also facing error like: PhalconException:: The method 'initialize' doesn't exist on model 'Category'

Comment: Remove the `parent::initialize();` line. Does it work then?